# 'Request failed with status code 500' error when trying to uploading document to amazon S3 with Node.js and Vuejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, http-status-code-500

We use:

1- Cognito for authentication

2- Api for uploading the document

3-Node.js and Vuejs

[image: Image to show the error]

Trying to uploading document to amazon S3 via API
There are a few steps that come before this step, company is created and then the upload API is looking for a company ID that is generated by the platform

[image]

error: 'Request failed with status code 500'

What are the reasons that can cause this error?
And how can we solve it?